# Android Studio - Simple app template connecting to SQL database

Tags: java, android, sql

I am currently in the early stages of learning Java and have written a simple app, however I would like a login/register activity via a database but I just can't figure it out. I have followed some tutorials but have not got one to work yet.

Does anyone know of a good working tutorial or downloadable project or even have a template they have written or used before?

Would really appreciate some help

Many thanks

Adrian

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on this topic that might be of help to you - https://inducesmile.com/android-snippets/android-login-and-registration-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: This is a good video tutorial too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M